# fetch data from table into php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table where i add rows dynamically using `j-query`
i want to fetch data from each fields in to my `php` and do somthing with it  when i press submit or maybe we can use `j-query` to loop around the table to get all the values and put it in an array  i do not know how to go about it can some one please help me. this is what i have so far

**Jquery.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
        });

        // Find and remove selected table rows
        $(".delete-row").click(function(){
            $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**Index.php**

```
<form>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
        </form>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
                    <td>Peter Parker</td>
                    <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
        <button type="button" class="Submit">Submit</button>
```

here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/t0gwedp9/)

Comment: into what php ?

Comment: yes i would like to fetch the data entered into php and process it

Comment: you want to send the table data to PHP? Like in this case Peter Parker..?

Comment: Yes i do want to send it to php 
wondering if they can be stored in a array or somthing

Comment: or maybe we can use j-query to loop around the table to get all the values and put it in an Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a hidden input to your form when you create your new row:

```
$(".add-row").click(function () {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
    markup += "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='" + name + "'>";
    markup += "<input type='hidden' name='email' value='" + email + "'>";

    $("table tbody").append(markup);
});
```

Then on the PHP side, you'd receive them like this in the `$_POST` array like this:

```
$_POST['name'], $_POST['email]
```

Since you want to be able to post more than one at a time, you can have them loded into an array, say called `customer` by naming them like this:

```
markup += "<input type='hidden' name='customer[0][name]' value='" + name + "'>";
markup += "<input type='hidden' name='customer[0][email]' value='" + email + "'>";
```

Then, `$_POST['customer']` would be an array of arrays, each with two keys `name` and `email`

All together it could look like:

```
var x = 0;

$(".add-row").click(function () {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();


    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
    markup += "<input type='hidden' name='customer[" + x + "][name]' value='" + name + "'>";
    markup += "<input type='hidden' name='customer[" + x + "][email]' value='" + email + "'>";
    x++;

    $("table tbody").append(markup);
});
```